# Is it possible to execute terminal-graphical-apps thru java-ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, ncurses, processbuilder, far

Is it possible to run subprocesses like Far/MidnightCommander (or other terminal app with ncurses/graphical-interface) from java application with ProcessBuilder or somehow other way?

Standart examples with ProcessBuilder works fine with something simple like **ping**

```
new ProcessBuilder().command("ping -n 4 google.com").start(); // :)
```

, but not worked at all with **far**

```
new ProcessBuilder().command("far").start(); // :(
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

These applications need access to a terminal device to work. If you started the java program from a terminal, you can use that same terminal by letting the new process *inherit* it:

```
new ProcessBuilder().inheritIO().command("top").start(); // :)
```

Otherwise, you need to start a new terminal emulator to run the program.

```
new ProcessBuilder().command("xterm", "top").start(); // :)
```

Comment: Thank you. Not worked in IDE (idea), but worked like a charm if starting from terminal
Final aim not using terminal thou(, could you advice smth for reading - couse for me was not clear from spec that "inheritIO" will bring it to life - at least in terminal?

Comment: Yes IDE output "terminals" often don't have a real terminal device attached to them.